# How to make a SharePoint 2013 "yes/no" list field to be displayed as a checkbox during inline editing?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have a "yes/no" field in a SharePoint 2013 list. In a default list view I can click "edit" link and get to inline editing of the list. In this case I can edit the "yes/no" field via a dropdown with values "yes" and "no". Like so:

[image]

But in my solution I have lots of records that must be clicked through by users as quickly as possible. And a checkbox is more convenient for this, but not a dropdown.

So is there any way (with or without custom development) to display a checkbox instead of a dropdown in inline editing mode? Like so:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked MSDN forum about the problem and got awesome links to a kind of developer reference for "Quick Edit" mode customizations in SharePoint 2013: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2ea0ec86-b6ba-49cd-afaa-3e1b7b5ba3ec/how-to-make-a-yesno-field-to-be-displayed-as-a-checkbox-during-inline-editing

Beside "Quick Edit" mode customizations, author of the referenced blog has many useful posts on JSLink field usage in SharePoint 2013.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid creating a SharePoint custom field type is the answer. Check out this guide

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb417414(v=office.12).aspx

It's custom dev but it's not to complex. After you custom field type is deployed, you must modify your column to use this type instead of yes/no.